# Is there any way to rename the PostgreSQL default operator names? For example, EXCEPT operator to MINUS. Is this doable?

Tags: postgresql, operators, except

Is there any way I can rename (or create alias for)the PostgreSQL default operator names? For example, EXCEPT operator to MINUS. Is this doable?

Comment: I would check [EnterpriseDB](https://www.enterprisedb.com/products/edb-postgres-platform)(it has Oracle compatibility: https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/en/9.6/DB_Compat_Oracle_Reference/Database_Compatibility_for_Oracle_Developers_Reference_Guide.1.088.html#pID0E0MVB0HA)

Comment: Why would you want to do something like that anyway?

Comment: @eurotrash : A client requirement who recently migrated from Oracle.. I believe.
I guess they just want to save the efforts involved in changing all the queries which use MINUS currently.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda : I need it in community PostgreSQL.

Comment: Update: 
After going through documents & speaking to some team members, it turns out that EXCEPT, UNION, INTERCEPT are not actually the operators (as mentioned at lot of places.. which is totally wrong) but KEYWORDS like SELECT, UPDATE.. we cannot really alter them in database. Any change to them or creating new one like them will only involve code change.